# Gnuplot plot only specified data sets

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have file with following structure:

```
#title
month graph1 graph2 graph3
January 1 2 3
February 2 3 4

#title2
month graph1 graph2 graph3
January 1 2 3
February 2 3 4
```

and I would like to plot only data set starting with title2.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a new enough gnuplot version, you can specify the name as the "index":

```
plot 'datafilename' index 'title2'
```

With older versions of gnuplot, this is still relatively straight forward using `sed`:

```
plot "< sed '1,/#title2/d' datafile" using ...
```

If you want to stop and not plot `#title3` data:

```
plot "< sed -n '/#title2/,/#title3/p' datafile" using ...
```

## Demo:

Test data --

```
#title
month graph1 graph2 graph3
January 1 2 3
February 2 3 4

#title2
month graph1 graph2 graph3
January 1 2 3
February 2 3 4

#title3
January 5 6 3
February 3 6 4.6
```

test script:

```
plot "< sed '1,/#title2/d' test.dat" using 2:4 w lines,\
     "< sed -n '/#title2/,/#title3/p' test.dat" using 2:4 w p ps 5
```

Produces this plot:

[image]

Notice that only the first line has points plotted at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much. Really helpful. And if I have more than 1 block with title2 I want to plot?